# Can't charge icons (awesome fonts)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've got an issue with my website, It's on WordPress and I've got one in French and one in English.

When I reach my website with this URL `www.bubbleblueagency.fr`, I can't see the icons, there is squares instead of arrows and I can't even click on my tabs as contact and stuff.

BUT when I reach it with URL `http://bubbleblueagency.fr` it WORKS.

The issues is only happening with the french version, because I managed to solve it with my English website. (`www.bubbleblueagency.com` or `www.bubbleblueagency.com`). I had the same issue and copy pasted this code in my `.htaccess` file :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
```

BUT I did the same on my french `.htaccess` and it doesn't work.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` is not really a good idea. Basically it allows all curious visitors to do with your page whatever the want, since you allow cross site scripting attacks that way. There is a reason why such requests are restricted...

Comment: For us to be able to help with fixing the real cause of the issue (as opposed to wild guessing or playing around with the symptoms) you need to add much more details to your question: the exact definition of those icons in the html markup, your server side setup and rewriting logic and the entries your http server writes into its error log file...

Comment: I think the issue come from my fonts theme " awesome fonts " (that are not really awesome to me) . I red somewhere it's a issue with my "cross - server".

Comment: Might be, sure, but playing guessing games has little to do with programming.

Comment: The thing is that if I do not write these code lines my icons do not work.

Comment: We did understand that, sure. It is interesting that you don't make the slightest attempt to provide the information I asked for. May I ask _why_ no? Is there any particular reason why you want to _guess_ instead of debugging your issue to find a real fix?

Comment: Sorry it's just I don't even know how to answer it...

Comment: Sure, all fine, we all start somewhere and have to learn to use the tools we want to use. But you cannot do that by wildly trying things. You need to sit down, examine the situation you have so that you are able to find how to actually solve the issue you face. For that you have to find out what the actual issue is. So 1. learn about that error log file I mentioned (you need to anyway for the future), there are endless documentations for that on the internet. and 2. learn about the development console built into your browser and how to use it to examine requests.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the settig of your Content-Security-Policy on the .htaccess
try first to check it

Comment: Thanks, but my .htaccess is the same on my english and french and it works on the english and not on the french